# Converting NAD83 to NAD27 in PostgreSQL issue

Tags: postgis, postgresql, nad83, nad27

I need to convert NAD83 to NAD27, while doing that process in PostgreSQL it throws the same NAD83 answer for latitude and longitude,  PostGIS extension also enabled and I have all the requirement for use the ST_Transform function and PostGIS but the same NAD83 latitude and longitude value for NAD27 latitude and longitude.
For e.g nad83 latitude : 32.37761

This is the output I get for NAD27 latitude, longitude also same for example purpose I give latitude NAD27

[image]

Comment: which longitude are you using?

Comment: latitude(nad83) : 32.37761 
longitude(nad83) : -103.719137

Comment: your code/coordinates returns `POINT(-103.71864885052335 32.37748726344252)`, both under postgis 3.3.3, proj 8.3.1 and postgis 3.2.1 proj 7.2.1

Comment: could you please tell me how to check proj and postgis version

Comment: `select postgis_full_version();`